# Unrecognized format of image?

Tags: c#, wpf

today i have looked in something very interesting. I saw one project that use

```
<Geometry o:Freeze="True" x:Key="FaceBookGeometry">m 41.416254,90 c -0.327378,-7.4702 0.20833,-32.7284 0,-39.901 -5.386902,-0.2083 -4.521603,0.3274 -9.848987,0 0.20833,-5.50595 0.36436,-7.66666 0.126269,-13.32142 4.646472,0.0181 3.439989,-0.009 9.848987,-0.1894 0.09586,-3.7736 0.133082,-3.0791 0.126269,-7.38674 0.18259,-3.73943 -0.486609,-10.54308 4.293149,-14.96288 4.779758,-4.4198 13.606811,-3.64808 22.223356,-3.53554 -0.04417,5.73754 -0.03936,9.37986 0,12.87945 -5.049924,0.46388 -7.309188,-0.33689 -10.85914,1.26269 -1.403378,3.17794 -1.569601,4.80531 -1.262691,11.93242 3.147964,-0.13336 8.201788,-0.1378 12.626907,0 -0.995158,6.00899 -0.948285,7.62376 -1.767767,13.06882 -3.676625,0.088 -5.605721,-0.1488 -11.111678,0 -0.148814,6.756 0.357147,33.0107 0,40.1536 -6.428576,0.1786 -8.174438,-0.03 -14.394674,0 z</Geometry>
```

I am not sure what is this type. It illustrates image .. I think it is some kind of converted image in this numbers. I saw it on WPF C# APP.
My questions are:

1. Is it converted image
2. If yes, how can i convert image like that?

And of course the project is [github](https://github.com/HandyOrg/HandyControl/blob/0762db0fb4b4a7378d8b8b783d09d30e7c306092/src/Shared/HandyControlDemo_Shared/Resources/Themes/Basic/Geometries.xaml) !

Comment: Plain geometry (PathGeometry).
What prevents you from displaying and seeing the result?

Comment: It is a Geometry, and would typically be used with a Path or a GeometryDrawing in a DrawingImage, DrawingBrush or DrawingVisual. Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: As has been said it is a Geometry with a Path. Take a look at this MIcrosoft documentation. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

This is the letter "f":

```
   <Grid xmlns:o="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" >
        <FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <Geometry o:Freeze="True" x:Key="FaceBookGeometry">m 41.416254,90 c -0.327378,-7.4702 0.20833,-32.7284 0,-39.901 -5.386902,-0.2083 -4.521603,0.3274 -9.848987,0 0.20833,-5.50595 0.36436,-7.66666 0.126269,-13.32142 4.646472,0.0181 3.439989,-0.009 9.848987,-0.1894 0.09586,-3.7736 0.133082,-3.0791 0.126269,-7.38674 0.18259,-3.73943 -0.486609,-10.54308 4.293149,-14.96288 4.779758,-4.4198 13.606811,-3.64808 22.223356,-3.53554 -0.04417,5.73754 -0.03936,9.37986 0,12.87945 -5.049924,0.46388 -7.309188,-0.33689 -10.85914,1.26269 -1.403378,3.17794 -1.569601,4.80531 -1.262691,11.93242 3.147964,-0.13336 8.201788,-0.1378 12.626907,0 -0.995158,6.00899 -0.948285,7.62376 -1.767767,13.06882 -3.676625,0.088 -5.605721,-0.1488 -11.111678,0 -0.148814,6.756 0.357147,33.0107 0,40.1536 -6.428576,0.1786 -8.174438,-0.03 -14.394674,0 z</Geometry>
        </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <Path Fill="Aqua" Data="{DynamicResource FaceBookGeometry}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Most likely this is a collection of different logos.